# How to create many workbench moderation flows / scenarios

Tags: workbench

I want to manage many content types with the [workbench moderation module](https://www.drupal.org/project/workbench_moderation). Every content type should have its own states and transitions. I tried [Workbench Moderation Profile](https://www.drupal.org/project/workbench_moderation_profile) module, but it has many bugs (it's in alpha) that causes many problems for me so I'm looking for any alternatives.

I don't mind developing a custom module, but I don't know how this could be achieved. Are there other solutions here?

Comment: [Workflow](https://www.drupal.org/project/workflow)?

Answer (score -1):

I think what you need is [Workbench Moderation Types](https://www.drupal.org/project/workbench_moderation_types)

Comment: Why exactly was this downvoted?